# Absolute divs doesn't fade out

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout, absolute

i have a question for you

this is the xhtml

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="category1">
        <div id="product1"></div>
        <div id="product2"></div>
        <div id="product3"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="category2">
        <div id="product4"></div>
        <div id="product5"></div>
        <div id="product6"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the concept is:

- by default #container1 is shown on the website
- by clicking on the menu "container2" #container2 fades in and #container1 fades out
- i have a second level menu to select the products.. and that's the only thing that works fine.

productX are absolute positioned inside the containerX which are related positioned

the script looks fine to me, but the products divs doesn't fade out at all!

this is the script

```
function controlCategory(a) {
   $("#category1").fadeOut();
                        $("#category2").fadeOut();
   $(a).fadeIn();
 }



     $(function () {

  $("#anchor1").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   controlCSS(this);
   controlCategory("#category1");
  });

           $("#anchor2").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   controlCSS(this);
   controlCategory("#category2");
  });

 });
```

does anybody know why the category divs doesn't fade out????

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*Update for updated question:* the code you posted works, though it's a bit glitchy the fade works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/3jKvQ/).  Something *outside* your question (perhaps a parent is hidden?) is interfering here.

---

*Previous answer:* Your IDs don't match, you have `#category1` for your selector but your elements have `id="container1"`, so your jQuery selectors just aren't finding any elements.  Just change either side so they match up.

Comment: This is the same as what I posted a few seconds before you. Isn't amazing how quick these things get answered?? :)

Comment: @Plaudit - Yup, formatting takes a few seconds longer to post ;)

Comment: check the code you posted on fiddle, i update fades to slides and added css.

check how the categories slides up and down, but the text just pop.

http://jsfiddle.net/andyvasile/3jKvQ/6/

Answer (score 0):

Is the javascritpt code for the html code? In the html you have containerX ids and your javascript has categoryX ids.